# How can I get `cos-extensions install gpu` to work on a Google Cloud VM?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, nvidia, google-container-optimized-os

I'm trying to set up a container-optimized OS (COS) on GCE with a GPU, following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-gpus. After creating the VM, it says to ssh in and run `cos-extensions install gpu`. That works; you can see during the install it runs `nvidia-smi` which prints out the driver version (440.33.01) and connects to the card.

But it installs the nvidia bins and libs in `/var/lib/nvidia`, which is mounted as `noexec` in this OS (it's very locked down). That means none of the libs or utilities work. And when you mount them to a docker container, they don't work there either; they're still noexec.

The only workaround I've found is to copy the whole `/var/lib/nvidia` dir to a tmpfs scratch disk and use it from there.
Am I using it wrong, or is it just broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look to be a containerd issue but rather a Container-Optimized OS  expected behaviour due to COS provides another level of hardening by providing security-minded default values for several features.

If you look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#filesystem), for Container-Optimized OS filesystem, everything under `/var` is mounted as no-exec except for

- `/var/lib/google`
- `/var/lib/docker`
- `/var/lib/toolbox`

Those are mounted with writable, executable and stateful properties.

On the other hand, Ubuntu containerd does not have the same strict exec/noexec depending on the mount like with COS, so, it could be a good idea to use Ubuntu based images instead of COS as a workaround.

Another option is to copy the contents of the `/var/lib/nvidia`under another mount point that was not mounted using the noexec option, as you already did.

Comment: Trying to understand the solution, this is about the 6th thread I've read on it and I'm struggling a bit, so we should either copy `/var/lib/nvidia` to another mount point (not sure what this means), or create a new VM with Ubuntu (wasn't an option on creation for some reason) ?

Comment: Three years later, still doesn't work. Moreover these days it doesn't even install - exits with `no space left on device` error. Shame.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I wasn't doing anything wrong. This is confirmed now as a bug in `cos-extensions`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164134488

Odd, because it seems like this would have shown up in testing.

There aren't any good production workarounds at the moment, because as a user it's hard to modify COS's behavior without some advanced scripting.

Comment: You are right, you weren't doing anything wrong, it seems that it is not the only error with COS imagens, there is another post https://issuetracker.google.com/159702288 that is reporting  Cos_conainerd images are mounting application volumes with noexec option, As I mentioned it could be an option to use Ubuntu as they did in that post.

Comment: There's no option to use Ubuntu. Can you link the source of this information?